# Consuming Facelets from a JAR leads my WAR to interpret the "JSF viewId" as a .jsp instead of .jsf

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm afraid this question might not be as "close ended" as a StackOverflow question should be. Hopefully, I'm wrong.

**Context**
We have a project (the typical Java EE with a JSF web GUI) that, due to requirement's specificities, we needed to split in two projets. One of these new split projects is a subset of the previous, with some slight differences.

So, from ORIGINAL_JAVAEE_WEBAPP.war we created: ORIGINAL_JAVAEE_WEBAPP-Proj01.war and ORIGINAL_JAVAEE_WEBAPP-Proj02.war.

In order to avoid redundancy we've decide to create a JAR file with all the facelets, managed beans and related pojos. The idea was that each WAR would include this JAR, use whatever they need and, then, the WAR would have the specific pages, logos, ...

**The problem**
I've created a simple example just to practice having a JAR file with facelets and having two WAR files including and using these facelets. In this example, things worked flawlessly.

Nevertheless, "the real world" is not that simple. Our project also relies on Primefaces, Spring Core and Spring Security, just to mention a few.

The implementation is not yet finished - far from it. Right now, under the same Maven project, I've created the JAR module, moved the beans and the facelets to that module and included it as a dependency in the WAR file module.

The problem is that, now, my "FacesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()" tells me that viewId is "someName.jsp" and not "someName.jsf". This simple change messes up with our "legacy" "authentication phase listener" (a phase listener to ensure that a user is logged in and redirect accordingly) implementation.

So, what can be happening here? Do any of you have any hint of what my next steps might be in order to track the root source of this problem?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the JSF ViewHandlers registered for the FacesContext. What version of JSF are you using and are there any view handlers defined in the JSF context xml.
Also please check in the web.xml the context params :javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX, javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPING